# Split string on whitespace OR dash only. Java Applet

Tags: java, regex, split, applet

I'm trying to split a space AND a dash character between words in a string array. The following code shows what kind of result I am after.

Code:

```
String[] wordSplit = txtInput.split (" ") && txtInput.split ("-");
```

input:

```
hello world hello-world
```

expected output:

```
there are: 4 word(s) of length 5.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use set of characters(`[..]`); it matches one of character listed.

```
String[] wordSplit = txtInput.split("[-\\s]")
```

Example:

```
class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = "hello world hello-world".split("[-\\s]");
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
hello
world
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a character class:

```
String[] wordSplit = txtInput.split("[ -]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
        String str = "hello world hello-world";
        String[] splitArray = str.split("[-\\s]");
        System.out.println("Size of array is :: "+splitArray.length);
```

Output : `4`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use more delimiters in one split.
Like this:

```
  String[]wordSplit = txtInput.split(" |\\-");
```